# How to persist a Materialize chips input as valid once a chip is entered?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, materialize

I'm currently validating a large, multi-section form using Materialize and jQuery-Validate and running into an issue with chips inputs where, once you press 'enter' to create a chip, the input 'resets' and triggers the validation's "required field" error msg. I can see in the dev console, pressing "enter" is toggling a valid/error class on the input (which is what hides/shows the error) as well as an aria-invalid attribute that toggles true/false. I also see a div with the class "chip" added above the input for each chip created. Here's an example of the output with a couple of chips:

```
<div class="chips chips-placeholder input-field col s12 m6">
   <div class="chip" tabindex="0">chip1<i class="material-icons close">close</i></div>
   <div class="chip" tabindex="0">chip2<i class="material-icons close">close</i></div>
   <input id="dfullname" name="dfullname" data-error=".errorTxt15" class="input error" autocomplete="off" placeholder="+Name" aria-describedby="dfullname-error" aria-invalid="true">
    <div class="errorTxt15">
        <div id="dfullname-error" class="error" style="">This field is required.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been playing around with Materialize's methods for chips (onChipAdd and onChipDelete) and scouring SO because I can't even get a console.log out of them. I was thinking that I might be able to leverage them somehow (in pseudocode, 'onChipDelete check if the input is empty')

Have also tried basic if/else logic checking for .chip class (i.e., 'if it exists log this, if it doesn't log that') but neither are yielding the results I'm after.

So, for a given input, how can I ensure/check that the input remains valid if a chip exists on it and trigger it as invalid if there are no chips? I've created a starter pen here and posted the code below:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRmNag

For the code to work, the following have to be added (all available on CDNs):

- Materialize (both CSS/JS)
- jQuery
- jQuery Validate

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="portal" action="#">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="chips chips-placeholder input-field col s12 m6">
        <input id="dfullname" name="dfullname" data-error=".errorTxt15" class="input" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="errorTxt15"></div> 
      </div>
      <div class="chips chips-placeholder input-field col s12 m6">
        <input id="efullname" name="efullname" data-error=".errorTxt16" class="input" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="errorTxt16"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row center-align">
      <div class="col s12">
        <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large btn-cyan">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-field div.error {
  position: relative;
  top: -.25rem;
  left: 0rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: red;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

JS:

```
// Add custom validation for chips
$.validator.addMethod('validatechips', function(value, element) {
  if (!$('.chip')) {
    return this.optional(element) || value !== '';   
  } else {
    return false;  
  }
}, 'This is a required field.');


// Initialize chips
$('.chips').chips();
$('.chips-placeholder').chips({
  placeholder: '+Name', 
  secondaryPlaceholder: '+Name'
});


// Initialize jQuery-validate
$('#portal').validate({
  rules: {
    dfullname: {validatechips: true},
    efullname: {validatechips: true}
  },
  errorElement: 'div',
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    var placement = $(element).data('error');
    if (placement) {
      $(placement).append(error);
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You must not rely solely on CodePen to show us code.  As per site rules, FAQ, and best practices, enough relevant code to construct a demo must also be posted within the OP.  This ensures SO's search can index as well as keeping question valid when CodePen's link goes bad.

Comment: I've answered a couple thousand questions about jQuery Validate and I could probably help if you would explain a little bit about chips... what is their purpose?

Comment: *"how can I ensure/check that the input remains valid if a chip exists on it and trigger it as invalid if there are no chips?"* ~ you don't.  That's the purpose of the validation plugin; to evaluate your defined rules and decide if an input is valid or invalid upon data entry.  If you need to check if a chip exists, then you need to write a custom method to do that.  [Search SO for `addMethod()` under the jQuery Validate tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+.addMethod%28%29).

Comment: @Sparky Thanks. I've added the code to the OP. I don't think it's as much an issue with Validate not working the way it should, but more with intercepting what Materialize is doing and adding the logic. Chips resemble tags in Wordpress. In Materialize, you can have a text input, type some text and press enter to create a tag. RInse, repeat to create multiple tags. https://materializecss.com/chips.html

Comment: Regardless, if you need to "make" something valid or invalid, that's the job of the validation plugin.  In order for jQuery Validate to do that, it needs a rule/method.  Any event handler function that bypasses the validation plugin potentially creates issues that can break the normal functioning of jQuery Validate.

Comment: Makes sense, I've updated the code above and pen, adding a basic method to validate chips (replacing required: true) but I'm still struggling badly with the logic. I only want to show an error if the input is completely empty. Not if a user is typing or if there are chips showing.